# Multiple user facebook sharer

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I created an angular app that allows users to take pictures from a touchscreen inside a shop.

Those users must be able to share these pictures on facebook. The problem is that once the first one has been logged-in to facebook via the sharer, it stores a session cookie and the next person who want to share his photo will be logged as the previous one.

I was thinking of something like : Share the photo button -> Ask facebook email & password credentials -> photo is shared on user wall -> user is automatically disconnected

Is there a way around this problem ?

Comment: Such “kiosk” apps are a bad idea anyway; there is a high chance that multiple users logging in on the same device will trigger Facebook’s security algorithms. And when that happens, the results can range from your user’s being annoyed (because they have to perform additional confirmation steps next time they log in), to your app getting blocked by Facebook. Device Login would be the proper way to handle this, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/for-devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/for-devices

Don´t just present the default login process, it will come with those session cookie issues and other problems (2 step verification, for example).

Also, NEVER EVER ask users for their credentials, especially their password. That´s not how Facebook Login works, and people hopefully don´t do that.

Comment: This solution seems a little bit tedious for the user. They do not necessarily have their phone with them. Plus the logout process is as complicated as the usual facebook login.

I was thinking of something like : Share the photo button -> Ask facebook email & password credentials -> photo is shared on user wall -> user is automatically disconnected

Comment: then there is no way to implement this in a serious way. every user should have 2 step verification activated on his account (if not, people, PLEASE tell them to do it), so they MUST have their phone with them to login with facebook. and then there is the issue with multiple logins at one device, facebook will definitely detect it - a lot of people tried to do this and they all had the same problems.

Comment: also, and this is VERY important: NEVER EVER ask users for their email and (especially) password. every user who enters his password at some random computer deserves a slap in the face.

Comment: Well thank you then, i'll think about another way to add a social feature to the product :)

Comment: just use device login, that´s the correct solution. why would people not have their phone with them anyway?